# Joomla noob, WWW title issue

Tags: joomla-3.x, cms

SO i'm no Joomla expert by any means of the imagination.

My uncle has a website, that runs off Joomla and has this awkward issue.

When accessing the website without a www like so:  http://website.com
his title reads

```
<title>Title without www in url</title>
```

when accessing the website with www like so:  http://www.website.com
his title reads

```
<title>Title is different when www is inside the url</title>
```

Any ideas what's causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Joomla backend, go to:

**Menus** >> **Main Menu** >> **Home** (or whatever your homepage menu item is)

Then go to the **Page Display** tab and you will see a field called **Browser Page Title**.

Fill this field in with the wording of your choice which should work for domains with and without `www`

Hope this helps

Comment: No luck... that's how we've been trying to fix it.

Comment: Have any changes been made to the htaccess file? Or do you have any 3rd party extensions being used for your URL management or SEO?

Comment: htaccess no, however they might be some SEO done. I can find out in a bit.

Comment: So it turned out, there was an SEO extension installed that was overwriting the default <title> settings. THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like this title could be generated from your template's `index.php` file (located in `JOOMLAROOT/templates/YOURTEMPLATE/index.php`).

To check this, log in to your Joomla admin area, and go to **Extensions** -> **Template Manager**.

Locate your default *front-end* template (#1, marked with a yellow star), and click the template *name* (#2).

[image]

You should now see a list of all your template files. Locate `index.php` in the list and click to edit the file.

[image]

Now look for `<title>` tags, `<title>Title without www in url</title>` or similar. There might be a PHP `if-else` statement to determine if the URL uses `www` or not. Here's an example on how this might look, but it could be different:

```
if(preg_match('/www/', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']))
{
  echo '<title>Title is different when www is inside the url</title>';
}
else
{
  echo '<title>Title without www in url</title>';
}
```

Comment: `preg_match()` is overkill for this answer.  `strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], 'www') !== false)` will be best practice.